# Firebase date range query to fetch documents that have starDate and endDate

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of tasks on my Firestore database like this:

```
"tasks": {
    v8NC4GovVOPe21fhwtp0 : {
        id: "v8NC4GovVOPe21fhwtp0"
        status: 0
        dateFrom: 30 april 2019 at 00:00:00 UTC-3
        dateTo: 05 may 2019 at 00:00:00 UTC-3
        ....
    },
    v7NC4GaxVOPe48ftstp1 : {
        id:"v7NC4GaxVOPe48ftstp1"
        status: 0
        dateFrom: 29 april 2019 at 00:00:00 UTC-3
        dateTo: 02 may 2019 at 00:00:00 UTC-3
        ....
    }
}
```

The document has a `dateFrom` field, which indicates the first date the user can start working on that task and an `dateTo` field, which indicates the last day the user have to finish that task.

I was trying to get all tasks from April 2019, which means the ones that either `dateFrom` or `dateTo` belongs to this month/year (in this example, if the month is April-2019, it must fetch both tasks).

On Android, I get the first date of the chosen month (`startDate`) and te last date from the chosen month (`endDate`) and I was trying to do something like:

```
val missionsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("/users").document(uid).collection("tasks")
        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("dateFrom", startDate).whereLessThanOrEqualTo("dateTo", endDate)
```

But I get an error saying that `All where filters other than whereEqualTo() must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'dateFrom' and 'dateTo'`.

I thought about some workarounds, but they all look bad and even though I could not find a nice solution, I'm sure there's gotta be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore allows to chain multiple "where()" methods to create more specific queries but only on the same field. As you can probably see in the official documentation regardin [Query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> Cloud Firestore does not support the following types of queries:
>
> - Queries with range filters on different fields, as described in the previous section.

So range filters on different fields are forbidden.

To achieve what you want, you need to query your database twice, once to fiter data using  a call to:

```
.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("dateFrom", startDate)
```

And second using a call to:

```
.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("dateTo", endDate)
```

But unfortunately you cannot use them in the same query.

**Edit:**

When we are designing a database schema, basically we structure it for our queries. So beside the above solution in which you can filter on one field in the query, and on the other field in your client-side code, there is also another approach in which you can combine the values of the two range into a single field in some way that will allow your use-case with a single field.

One of the most successful examples I've seen so far is the combination used in `Geohashes` to filter on latitude and longitude as explained by Frank van Puffelen in the following video:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q

Knowing the difference in effort between these two solutions, I'd recommend using the first one.

There is also a third solution, in which you should to add all tasks from Mar-Apr into a single collection. Then you could query this new collection with:

```
 db.collection("tasks-aps-mar")
    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("day", 1)
    .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("day", 30);
```

Even a more general solution would be to store the tasks in a collection for each month, and then perform a query to get all the tasks that correspond with the desired month. In your use case, you should query your database to get the documents within one of each collection `tasks-mar-2019`, `tasks-apr-2019`, `tasks-may-2019` and so on.

Regarding your comment, using arrays won't help you at all since you cannot use range intervals.

Comment: By "querying it twice" you mean making two different calls to firebase and then creating a list with tasks that were fetched on both calls?

Comment: I understand that's a limitation on firebase and I really appreciate your help :)
However, I'm not sure if a solution that fetches more documents than my entire collection would be the way to go (considering pricing and reading time)

Comment: I thought about having a array of "month-year" so I can do something like this: `.whereArrayContains("months", "04-2019")`. What do you think about this option?

Comment: Currently this is what the docs states. Please also see my updated answer from alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful and I'm sorry it took me some time to accept your answer. It turns out the PO on my project decided to have only one date field, but regardless, those are the solutions we have on firebase land.